# Rspec send_data test not passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I can't seem to get this test to pass and I don't understand why.

controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe QuotationRequestsController, type: :controller do

  describe "GET download" do    
    it "streams the sample text as a text file" do
      #setup
      quotation_request = create(:quotation_request)
      file_options = {filename: "#{quotation_request.id}-#{quotation_request.client.name.parameterize}.txt", type: 'plain/text', disposition: 'attachment'}

      #exercise
      get :download, id: quotation_request

      #verification
      expect(@controller).to receive(:send_data).with(file_options) {@controller.render nothing: true}      
    end
  end
end
```

controller:

```
def download
  @quotation_request = QuotationRequest.find(params[:id])
  send_data @quotation_request.sample_text, {
    filename: @quotation_request.sample_text_file, 
    type: "text/plain",
    disposition: "attachment"
  }
end
```

Output of test:

```
1) QuotationRequestsController GET download streams the sample text as a text file
  Failure/Error: expect(@controller).to receive(:send_data).with(file_options) {
    @controller.render nothing: true
  }       
  (# <QuotationRequestsController:0x007ff35f926058>).send_data({
    :filename=>"1-peter-johnson.txt",
    :type=>"plain/text",
    :disposition=>"attachment"
  })  
  expected: 1 time with arguments: ({
    :filename=>"1-peter-johnson.txt",
    :type=>"plain/text", :disposition=>"attachment"
  })
  received: 0 times
  # ./spec/controllers/quotation_requests_controller_spec.rb:380:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  # -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I assume you're using `FactoryGirl.create`. Have you checked whether `create(:quotation_request)` successfully creates the record?

Comment: Yes I test for that. It creates the quotation_request.

Comment: Do you use pry or debugger for debugging test cases ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass 2 arguments 

`expect(@controller).to receive(:send_data).with(quotation_request.sample_text, file_options) {@controller.render nothing: true}`

Answer (score 3):

```
  #exercise
  get :download, id: quotation_request

  #verification
  expect(@controller).to receive(:send_data).with(file_options) {@controller.render nothing: true}
```

This is backwards. The expectation should come before the method call.

Comment: I reversed the above two lines and I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas ? How should I write this test?

Comment: This should be the solution, unless your controller action is not completing successfully.

Comment: The controller action is completing successfully as I can test it in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You write following:

1. Get file
2. Mock file

But right case is inverted:

1. Mock file
2. Get file

try following (using `before`):

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe QuotationRequestsController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET download" do   
    let(:quotation_request) { create(:quotation_request) }
    let(:file_options) { {filename: "#{quotation_request.id}-#{quotation_request.client.name.parameterize}.txt", type: 'plain/text', disposition: 'attachment'} }

    before do
      expect(@controller).to receive(:send_data)
         .with(file_options) { @controller.render nothing: true }
    end

    it "streams the sample text as a text file" do
      get :download, id: quotation_request
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails 5:

`expect(@controller).to receive(:send_data).with(quotation_request.sample_text, file_options) {@controller.head :ok}`

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43428992