# What to use instead of `render :text` (and `render nothing: true`) in rails 5.1 and later?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5.1 [removes a whole load of previously deprecated methods](https://blog.driftingruby.com/ruby-on-rails-5-1-0-deprecations/?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email). Among them is the old friend `render :text`.

It was very useful when you need to render *some* text, but don't want the overhead of a view template. Examples:

```
render text: "ok"
render text: t('business_rules.project_access_denied'), status: 401
```

What to use instead?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

The non-deprecated way is to use `render :plain`

[Rails Guide on Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-text):

> #### 2.2.6 Rendering Text
>
> You can send plain text - with no markup at all - back to the browser by using the `:plain` option to render:
>
> ```
> render plain: "OK"
> ```

#### Bonus

Instead of `render nothing: true` (also removed), one should now use `head :ok`. Does the same thing: sends http 200 response code, just the headers, no content.

Comment: This particular deprecation caused me 10 minutes of head scratching. Hence the self-answer.

Comment: This has got to be the number one cause for JSON parsing errors... :D

Comment: @max: no doubt. This, and controller rendering an html page with beautified stacktrace on exceptions :)

Comment: When was this deprecated? The 5.1.0.rc1 CHANGELOG just says "Remove deprecated support to `:text` in `render`" (and `:nothing`, sigh) but you'd think the "we're deprecating this" note in some CHANGELOG would tell you what to use instead.

Comment: What a PITA. Any idea what to use instead of `:nothing`? I've been putting off upgrading out of 4.2 because of this sort of nonsense. At least the `skip_action_callback` deprecation notice tells you to use the "individual skip_callback methods" instead.

Comment: @muistooshort: instead of `render nothing: true` you should use `head :ok`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Gotta' bookmark this for the inevitable liquor and anger fuelled upgrade process :)

Comment: @muistooshort: how's that upgrade process? Did you get to do it yet? :)

Comment: Not yet, I have stockpiled enough "supplies" ;)

Comment: I love Rails, but cmon, was this deprecated just to make our upgrade path miserably? The amount of braking changes is incredible.

Comment: a lot of the recent changes were pretty arbitrary, and made upgrading painful :(

Comment: You look like you're citing something - can you include the link?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: why, it's the relevant rails guide, of course. Added the link.

Comment: upgrading to 5.0 was relatively okay. 5.1 turned out to be a bigger minefield than expected o.o

Comment: @muistooshort: did you upgrade yet? Rails 6 is coming out, the longer you postpone, the more painful it'll be :)

Comment: Switched projects before I could get clearance for an upgrade so the 4.2->5.2 upgrade became not my problem (my favorite type of problem :), got to start a new app instead of dealing with an app with a legacy from Rails2/MongoDB. Now I get to whinge about Active Storage instead.

Comment: tripped me up that you don't `render head: :no_content`, it's just `head :no_content` if it saves anyone else a few minutes...