# railstutorial ruby on rails Missing template in tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in the very beginning of my career as a Ruby on Rails developer
I'm reading online a book named "Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Rails 5)
Learn Web Development with Rails"
I've made an 'hello world' app following the book instructions.

> app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def hello
    render text: "hello world!"
  end

end
```

> config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'application#hello'

end
```

Now I receive that error

> Missing template application/hello with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html,
>
> :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: 
>   app_path/app/views

I have

> /app/view/layouts/application.html.erb

in my project so that should theoretically be the view, shouldn't it?

So am I missing something?
How could I fix it?

Comment: i'm no expert but it seems it might be deprecated,  this says it's deprecated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428991/what-to-use-instead-of-render-text-and-render-nothing-true-in-rails-5-1    and to use render plain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Missing template application/hello with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb,
>   :html,:builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
>   app_path/app/views

In addition to @Sujan Adiga's answer, `render :text` misdirect people to think that it would render content with `text/plain` *MIME type*. However, `render :text` actually sets the response body directly, and inherits the *default response MIME type*, which is `text/html`. So *Rails* tries to find the **HTML template** and spits out with that error if unable to find.

To avoid this, you can either use `content_type` option to set the *MIME type* to `text/plain` or just use `render :plain`

```
render text: "hello world!", content_type: 'text/plain'
```

*or*

```
render plain: "hello world!"
```

Comment: I can't get `render text: "hello world!", content_type: 'text/plain'` to work, I get the same error as without the `content_type: "text/plain"` argument, but i've heard render text is deprecated anyway.  as is mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428991/what-to-use-instead-of-render-text-and-render-nothing-true-in-rails-5-1   I find  `render plain` works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
render plain: "hello world!"
```

when you do `render text: ...`, it tries to render template with name `hello.erb|haml|jbuilder|...` and passes `text= "hello world!"` as data.

[Ref](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

Answer (score 1):

```
render html: "hello, world!"
```

will do the job