# rails upgrade render text gives missing template error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-on-rails-5.1

When upgraded the rails application from rails 5.0 to rails 5.2 I am getting the following error when I am trying to login using saml

```
Missing template sso/authsetup/saml, application/saml with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :axlsx, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/app/be/app/views/custom/1" * "/home/app/be/app/views" * "/usr/local/bundle/gems/ruby/2.5.0/gems/letter_opener_web-1.4.1/app/views" * "/usr/local/bundle/gems/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/ckeditor-bbc03cf0b757/app/views" * "/usr/local/bundle/gems/ruby/2.5.0/gems/kaminari-core-1.2.2/app/views" * "/usr/local/bundle/gems/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootstrap5-kaminari-views-0.0.1/app/views"
```

I am getting this error on this line

```
render :text => "Omniauth setup phase.", :status => 404
```

I have gone through a few of the https://github.com/thoughtbot/ember-cli-rails/issues/527 & [What to use instead of `render :text` (and `render nothing: true`) in rails 5.1 and later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428991/what-to-use-instead-of-render-text-and-render-nothing-true-in-rails-5-1) and try to update this line

```
render :plain => "Omniauth setup phase.", :status => 404

head :not_found

respond_to do |format|
    format.html { head :not_found  }
end
```

But none of it works. Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Got any luck ?