# Render the body via different method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

i have been working on a specific use case, where we need to render something like

`render body: nil`
`render nothing: true`

so these two things has to used in different methods, like

```
def render_method
  if some_condition
    render body: nil
  else 
    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

so while calling this, from another method like

```
def method2
  render_method
end
```

Anyhow this is rendering to the method 2.

Is there any way for this to render to the method which called above?

Comment: "anyhow this is rendering to the method 2" - what does this mean exactly, "render to a method"?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i mean the render_method, from where the second method gets called.

Comment: I still have no idea what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to call a method that renders differently depending on a condition. And I would basically work like the methods in your question, with the only difference that both, `body: nil` and `nothing: true` or invalid parameters to the [`render`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderer.html#method-i-render) method. When you elaborate on what you want to achieve and what should be returned in both cases, then we might be able to help.

Comment: RE `nothing: true`: it used to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428991/what-to-use-instead-of-render-text-and-render-nothing-true-in-rails-5-1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to fully understand your question but you have to add return if you are in this case:

```
def index
  if condition
    render html: 'HTML HERE' and return
  end 

  render json: {}
end
```